# NSCalendar date error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I'm trying to use `NSCalendar` with `NSIslamicCalendar` identifier.
But the day result is not good, her's my code:

```
NSCalendar *calandar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];    
NSDateComponents *components = [calandar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger theDay = [components day];
NSInteger theMonth = [components month];
NSInteger theYear = [components year];


[components setDay:theDay];
[components setMonth:theMonth];
[components setYear:theYear];
NSDate *thisDate = [calandar dateFromComponents:components];    
NSLog(@"year=%i month=%i day=%i",theYear,theMonth,theDay);
NSLog(@"thisdate = %@", [thisDate description]);


NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i-%i",theYear,theMonth,theDay];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *datee = [formatter dateFromString:strDate];
NSLog(@"datee = %@", [datee description]);
```

logs:

```
year=1434 month=2 day=28              ----> all good (it's islamic calandar)
thisdate = 2013-01-09 23:00:00 +0000  ----> not good (we are in 2013-01-10 not 09).
datee = 1434-02-27 23:19:16 +0000     ----> not good (we are in 1434-02-28 not 27)
```

As you can see the first date is correct not the 2 other, and also time is not correct (when i compile it's about 14:20) and it differs between the last 2 last log (23:00:00 vs 23:19:16).

this code is in my viewDidload: function and no other code is running before or after.

Also if i want get the number of days in a month i get one more day:

```
NSCalendar *c = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];
NSRange dayRange = [c rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:date];
NSLog(@"dayRange.length = %i",dayRange.length);
```

log:

```
dayRange.length = 30 -----> but this islamic month have 29 day not 30.
```

what is the problem and how can i fix it ? thank you.

***Edit:***

it seems to be the same for `NSGregorianCalendar` in one difference is that the day count is correct.
log using `NSGregorianCalendar`

```
 year=2013 month=1 day=10                -----> all good
 thisdate = 2013-01-09 23:00:00 +0000    -----> not good
 datee = 2013-01-09 23:00:00 +0000       -----> not good

 dayRange.length = 31 ------------------------> all good
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datee = 1434-02-27 23:19:16 +0000` maybe this is a specialty of the islamic calendar? as in Islam the times of prayers are related to the sunrise equation it could try to express the sun time on a certain point. i.E. in Saudi Arabia the Sun time is the only valid time for religious reasons. they refuse to give the same land one time. If the sun is at the highest point, it is 12:00. as this differs a lot in cities just few hundred kilometers apart, the cities of Saudi Arabia have different times.

Note, that although in any other islamic country normal timezones are used, this implementation would make sense, as probably the most valid use case for the islamic calendar are calculation of religious events — and it becomes much easier, if I use Sun time.

---

With this code

```
    NSCalendar *islamicCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];

     NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    [islamicCalendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&today interval:NULL forDate:today];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar:islamicCalendar];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

    //english output 
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

    NSString * islamicDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"%@", islamicDateString);
```

it results in

```
2013-01-11 01:13:46.110 islamicCalendarTest[18346:303] Friday, Safar 29, 1434 12:00:00 AM Central European Standard Time
```

NSDateFormatter takes in account your default timezone.

Comment: +1 for this information. I don't know for others but i find this very informative and interesting.

Comment: Thank you for the information +1 :)
in fact may plan is to build an islamic calendar for muslims(religious not civil one) and make it open open source because i don't find any like Kal calendar or Tapku for iOS/mac osx, what is the best approach you advice me to follow ?

Comment: first you should confirm, it it is true, what I am guessing…

Comment: @user2602081: your disapproved suggested edit is clearly a strong insult.

Answer (score 2):

`time is not correct (when i compile it's about 14:20) and it differs between the last 2 last log (23:00:00 vs 23:19:16).`

This is because of time zone difference between GMT and your local zone.

Comment: But in my mac the local zone is set to Paris and i'm in Tunisia so between me and GMT-time there is just 1 hour.

Comment: So Anoop is correct. you are ommiting the hour and minute, so thes time is set to 0:00 in your timezone, that is one hour ahead of GMT.

Comment: Note that a NSDate does not describe a date, as you would may understand it from the english language as a date, but a point in time. Actually it is just a number of seconds passed by this the start of the era.

Comment: @vikingosegundo : but his other problem is with date islamic calender, which i dont have any idea how it shows difference in dates.

Comment: I wrote a comment about that below the question, though I have no idea, if my statement is correct.

Comment: Thats a very interesting answer, I live in India, have dozens of friends who follow Islam, but I was unaware of this. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I lived in Istanbul for a while. While they have one timezone for the whole Turkey during ramadan you can follow iftah (the breaking of the fasting at dusk) in TV at minute level for every city. I found it quite interesting that between Istanbul and Ankara were (I think) 17 minute difference. It gives you a sense, of who fast the earth rotates.

Comment: thank you for replay, so if i understand, i have to use NSCalandar instead NSDate, so i have to make my own class to handle Date?

but as you can see in my edit in question, i have the same problem with Gregorian Calendar so i think that i have other problem no ?

Comment: A date is just a point in time. The calendar gives it a context. you dont have a real problem, as it is just a timezone matter. that is easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create a Gregorian Calendar
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

// Set up components of a Gregorian date
NSDateComponents *gregorianComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"[In Gregorian calendar ->] Day: %ld, Month: %ld, Year:%ld",
      (long)[gregorianComponents day],
      (long)[gregorianComponents month],
      (long)[gregorianComponents year]);


gregorianComponents.day = [gregorianComponents day];
gregorianComponents.month = [gregorianComponents month];
gregorianComponents.year = [gregorianComponents year];

// Create the date
NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:gregorianComponents];



// Then create an Islamic calendar
NSCalendar *hijriCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCivilCalendar];

// And grab those date components for the same date
NSDateComponents *hijriComponents = [hijriCalendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit |
                                                               NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                                               NSYearCalendarUnit)
                                                     fromDate:date];


NSLog(@"[In Hijri calendar ->] Day: %ld, Month: %ld, Year:%ld",
      (long)[hijriComponents day],
      (long)[hijriComponents month],
      (long)[hijriComponents year]);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here are good approaches, but just from scientific perspective. But indeed as a developer lives in Turkey and know what this issue stems from, Apple has more than one islamic calendar identifiers

```
- NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic
- NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil
- NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicTabular
- NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivilUmmAlQura
```

I think what he is looking for is `NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil`. My app also has a Hijri calendar inside it and `NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil` resolved the issue