# NSDateFormatter with NSIslamicCalendar doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I'm converting Greogorian date to Hijri date using `NSDateFormatter` with an `NSIslamicCalendar` set as the formatter calendar using `setCalendar` method the problem is that the result Hijri String always one day more than the actual date for example if we use the below code to convert today's greg date to Hijri the out put will be `18 Rabi' || 1435` which is wrong as today is `17 Rabi' || 1435`, i saw many posts for these problem like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259397/nscalendar-date-error) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194820/converting-a-gregorian-date-string-to-islamic-date-gives-correct-incorrect-res) i tried all the possible solutions in those posts but with no mean!!  here's the getter for the hijriDateFormatter property:

```
-(NSDateFormatter*)hijriDateFormatter{
if (!_hijriDateFormatter) {
    _hijriDateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
}

[_hijriDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]; // i trie aslo to set TimeZone as localTimeZone
 _hijriDateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[_hijriDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM, yyyy"];
[_hijriDateFormatter setCalendar:self.hijriCalendar];
return _hijriDateFormatter;
```

}

also the getter for the property `hijriCalendar`:

```
-(NSCalendar*)hijriCalendar{
if (!_hijriCalendar) {
    _hijriCalendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];
}
return _hijriCalendar;
}
```

here i get the converted HijriDate as a string:

```
NSString *convertedHijriDate=[self.hijriDateFormatter stringFromDate:GregorianDate];
```

Given that `GregorianDate` is today's date and its value is:`2014-02-17 09:48:47 +0000` please help me in these issue, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Islamic calendars are difficult. There are apparently different mathematical formulas in accepted use which lead to different results. In addition, the *correct* calendar is based on actual observations of the moon, giving different results depending on your location and for example the weather (whether a new moon is visible on a given day can depend on the weather; on a fine day a new moon might be just barely visible while on a cloudy day it couldn't be seen). In summary, there can be different numbers that can all be "correct".

I'd suggest reading as much about the subject as you can and then figuring out what are the answers that you want to display.